# Android alarm not being triggered

Tags: android, alarm

I"m sure this is something that is simple, but I'm not figuring it out. I'm trying to make a simple repeating alarm and it never gets triggered.  What I have is:

```
private void setupAlarms()
{
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RepeatingAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(HelloAndroid.this, 0, intent, 0);

    GregorianCalendar fifteenSeconds = (GregorianCalendar)Calendar.getInstance();
    fifteenSeconds.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    fifteenSeconds.set(Calendar.SECOND, 15);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), fifteenSeconds.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

This is called from the main onCreate call.

My alarm receiver:

```
public class RepeatingAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.hello, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

In my manifest, I have added:

```
<receiver android:name=".RepeatingAlarm" android:process=":remote" />
```

Any help, much appreciated

Comment: I am not sure if fifteenSeconds.getTimeInMillis() really return 15*60*1000 [ms]?

Comment: I think it doesn't. You can set the the calendar up to the number of seconds, but the milliseconds value will be different for 2 identically set times.

Comment: That was it.  Changed it 1000 and it popped up immediately.

Comment: @Jahmic: Please do not invoke an alarm every 15 seconds.

Comment: the 15 seconds was only to see if it was working. I realize it isn't a good practice.

Comment: Damian / r1k0, add your comment as answer and I'll check it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added an intent filter to your BroadcastReceiver?
Code might look something like this in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
    <receiver android:name=".RepeatingAlarm" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="intent id text" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and when creating your intent do something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("intent id text")
```

where the "intent id text" can be any string you use to identify your intent. Also Android alarms get reset if you reboot your device so that may be something you need to look into.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The misconfigured time was the issue.